# Access Search Subform + Update Query Subform?

Tags: forms, ms-access, office365

So I'm new to Access 365, and I'm working on a database for my church's cemetery. I have a "main" form that will house searches and the results of said searches (https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9u4R.png).

So I'd like to put a box on this form that when I press the "Run Query" button, updates with all records matching the criteria. I have the query working, and if I go into the individual search form and search, it works fine.

If I try dragging the query onto the main form, I get a SearchQuery subform, but when I go into form view, I have to fill out data before the form even loads. I need it to only update after I click the button, so that I can enter info, THEN search (https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaBAR.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKkkS.png). If I click cancel, it loads fine, but when I type in data to the search then press "Run Query", it still prompts me for the info (https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKcja.png).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I told you before, put the search criteria in the header of a form. Base your form on a query. Requery after entering the search criteria.

Comment: @Rene I'm very confused on how to do this. Do I create a form with a header then drag the query into it? Then put the search form in the body of the form? Like this: https://i.imgur.com/dK1pdkk.png? I know next to nothing about Access.

Comment: No, the query should be the RecordSource of form. Put your search controls in the header section. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Okay, I'm starting to get that, I now have the search form and records correctly on the form. So when I press the search button, do I use VB and filter the data? Is it just a string of SQL then Control.Filter = "sql/query"? Here's where I'm at: https://i.imgur.com/d4JzaN7.png (the button is just the run SearchQuery macro)

Comment: @June7 Any idea how to get the records to still show up in a table, but in the detail section?

Comment: Do you mean in a form detail section? I expect should just put controls bound to fields in detail section.

Comment: @June7 I looked at the link you send and used the VBA in my form, (link to all code: https://pastebin.com/v5q0ucjp) however every time I run, I receive "Run-time error '2427'...". I've looked it up, and there seemed to be a solution in VBA for this, but I'm not sure if that's what I want. I have the detail section of the form set as a Continuous Form, and I followed the guide too. Any ideas?

Comment: You are using a subform for the records. The referenced example does not employ a subform. Did you download Allen's example db to examine?

Comment: @June7 Yes I downloaded it and I copied off of it, I don't have any subforms in the search. The header has all unbound text boxes/controls. The detail section has only unbound controls for the results. Image here: https://i.imgur.com/yxe8uIz.png

Comment: Okay, the previous image showed a subform. What is the exact complete error message? Should edit your question with your efforts and results. Have you step debugged? I might have to examine db directly to assist further.

Comment: @June7 I only have sample data in so you can check it if you want ([Download DB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mYrAI5H2AeY1YFzLwd4EiHkk4xa6P5xn/view)). The error is "Run-time error '2427': You entered an expression that has no value." I have not step-debugged. Is that debugging with breakpoints and such?

Comment: Breakpoints, stepping, Print to immediate window - all useful debug techniques.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is constructing criteria with control names as the data to search in, must use table field names. Remove the `Result_` from each expression.

Coffin and Cremation radio buttons are within an OptionGroup control. This means you must test for the value of the OptionGroup, not the controls within the group. Clicking radio button sets value of the OptionGroup control. Following is revised code for the OptionGroup and checkboxes. Note removal of `Result_` - fix the other conditional expressions as well. Might want to rename the OptionGroup control.

```
'Coffin/Cremation
If Not IsNull(Me.optGroup) Then strFilter = strFilter & "([Coffin/Cremation] = " & Me.optGroup & ") AND "

'Veteran
If Not IsNull(Me.Veteran) Then strFilter = strFilter & "([Veteran] = " & Me.Veteran & ") AND "

'Monument
If Not IsNull(Me.Monument) Then strFilter = strFilter & "([Monument] = " & Me.Monument & ") AND "
```

Why is the Clear Search button using EmbeddedMacro? Code to clear search parameters:

```
Private Sub cmdReset_Click()
    'Purpose:   Clear all the search boxes in the Form Header, and show all records again.
    Dim ctl As Control

    'Clear all the controls in the Form Header section.
    For Each ctl In Me.Section(acHeader).Controls
        Select Case ctl.ControlType
        Case acTextBox, acComboBox, acCheckBox, acOptionGroup
            ctl.Value = Null
        End Select
    Next

    'Remove the form's filter.
    Me.FilterOn = False
End Sub
```

Consider using comboboxes instead of textboxes to help users enter valid data. Can still allow any input and use LIKE/wildcard. RowSource SQL could be like:
`SELECT DISTINCT [Last Name] FROM A ORDER BY [Last Name];`

Advise not to use space nor punctuation/special characters (only exception is underscore) in naming convention.

Comment: Thanks! Search works, kinda!

Last question: checkboxes don't update on search (https://i.imgur.com/dEl2YhD.png). Unchecking the search checkboxes results in no records, and checking one/both also results in the record checkboxes being triple state checked.

Comment: Checkboxes in Detail section need ControlSource set. Checking both search checkboxes results in no records because no records meet the criteria. Unchecking search checkboxes works for me. Of course, only returns records where the yes/no fields are False. Use the Clear Search button to return the search checkboxes to Null and they will not be included in the criteria. Might find this of interest http://allenbrowne.com/NoYesNo.html

Comment: Same for the Coffin/Cremation option group control. Use Clear Search button if don't want it considered in building search criteria.

Comment: Using your Coffin/Cremation code, the "Cremation" option displays all data, and selecting "Coffin" displays no data.

Comment: My suggested Coffin/Cremation code works for me. But glad you have all working satisfactorily.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any form from the `subform` as follows:
MainForm:  LOAN SETTLEMENT FORM

ex:

```
Forms![LOAN SETTLEMENT FORM]!txtEMP_ID.Value = Me.EMP_ID.Value

Forms![LOAN SETTLEMENT FORM]!txtEMP_NAME.Value = Me.EMP_NAME.Value
```